# First call to CLGeocoder always returns Zero

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using GeoCoder to grab the coordinates by sending it a zip code. The first response GeoCoder returns is always 0.000. As you can see below, I NSLog the value passed to weatherCall for lattitude from the geocoder and it is always 0.00000

If I simply refresh using the same method to set the zip code that is used here, the 2nd time it works just fine.

Here are my methods:

```
-(void)updateWeather
{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

zip = [defaults objectForKey:@"zip"];

NSLog(@"%@", zip);

if (zip == NULL) {

    [defaults setObject:@"95014" forKey:@"zip"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"zip updated to: %@", zip);
}


// check time of last fetch, if more than 0.5 hours, refresh

NSDate *lastFetch = [defaults objectForKey:@"time"];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastFetch];
double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
float hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;

NSLog(@"hours between %.2f", hoursBetweenDates);

if (hoursBetweenDates > 0.5 || refreshNow == 1 || isnan(hoursBetweenDates)){

refreshNow = 0;

    NSLog(@"hours between was probably nan or hours between was wrong");

// get the coords from the zip

CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geoCoder geocodeAddressString:zip completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


    NSLog(@"geo was passed %@ for zip", zip);

    cityName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is currently",placemark.locality];
    [defaults setObject:cityName forKey:@"cityName"];

    CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
    __block CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = location.coordinate;

    [defaults setDouble:currentLocation.latitude forKey:@"lat"];
    [defaults setDouble:currentLocation.longitude forKey:@"longi"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    // call the weather function from end of this block

    [self weatherCall];

}]; // end getting coords

    // begin cached version below this
}  else {
            cityName = [defaults objectForKey:@"cityName"];
            NSString *currentTemp = [defaults objectForKey:@"currentTemp"];
            NSString *desc = [defaults objectForKey:@"desc"];

            // update labels to display variables
            self.cityLabel.text = cityName;
            self.tempLabel.text = currentTemp;
            self.descriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", desc]; 

    } // end cached version



}
```

Here is the weatherCall referenced above:

```
-(void)weatherCall
{
// set coords to defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
float lat = [[defaults objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
float longi = [[defaults objectForKey:@"longi"] floatValue];


// get current conditions

ForecastKit *forecast = [[ForecastKit alloc] initWithAPIKey:@"a24a3ebfb5aef389141cfcdc479e31b7"];

[forecast getCurrentConditionsForLatitude:lat longitude:longi success:^(NSMutableDictionary *responseDict) {

    NSLog(@"first call was sent %f", lat);

    NSString *currentTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i\u00B0",[responseDict[@"temperature"] intValue]];
    [defaults setObject:currentTemp forKey:@"currentTemp"];

    NSString *feelsLike = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i\u00B0",[responseDict[@"apparentTemperature"] intValue]];
    [defaults setObject:feelsLike forKey:@"feelsLike"];

    NSString *desc = [responseDict[@"summary"] capitalizedString];
    [defaults setObject:desc forKey:@"desc"];

    // update labels to display variables
    self.cityLabel.text = cityName;
    self.tempLabel.text = currentTemp;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", desc];


    // set temp color and hint image based on temp

    int temp = [responseDict[@"temperature"] intValue];
    [defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",temp] forKey:@"temp"];

    if (temp < 32){
        self.tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    } else if (temp > 32 && temp < 60){
        self.tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74/255.0f green:136/255.0f blue:124/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    } else if (temp > 59 && temp < 80) {
        self.tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:138/255.0f green:251/255.0f blue:203/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    } else {
        self.tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:143/255.0f green:87/255.0f blue:67/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    }


    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:0.7];

    // set fetch time

    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"time"];

    [defaults synchronize];


} failure:^(NSError *error){

    NSLog(@"Currently %@", error.description);

}];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] init]`?  Shouldn't it be `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`?

Comment: You are right, that was a typo. i have fixed all instances where I did that. It did not fix the issue.

Comment: The issue may be that in the `if (zip == NULL)`, code sets the default to 95014 in NSUserDefaults but the `zip` variable is still `nil`.

Comment: I have also tried with a static zip string supplied to the geocoder: 

    [geoCoder geocodeAddressString:@"54913" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];